# Set Sentry Performance Transaction in IActionFilter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, sentry

I want to Start a transaction for every ControllerAction that is hit.

I made an `SentryFilter : IActionFilter` and start/finish the transaction in `OnActionExecuting`/`OnActionExecuted`. The transaction is started/finished in the filter and sent to Sentry but:

`SentrySdk.GetSpan()` returns null in the ControllerAction and in the Services the Controller uses.
If I start the Transaction inside the ControllerAction, `SentrySdk.GetSpan()` is working in the Service.

If I do it inside a BaseController, it behaves the same as in the Filter.

How can I make it work that I dont need to manually start a transaction in every Action?

Comment: Could you please add some working and nonworking code you have tried?

Comment: This is ASP.NET Core? The Sentry SDK should already create transactions for you in the middleware pipeline. Is this not the case?